# Mongo export in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using spring data mongo-db and I'm looking for a way to run a mongoexport command in my code.

Is there a way to do this? maybe using mongo template?

I saw this:

```
public com.mongodb.CommandResult executeCommand(com.mongodb.DBObject command,int options)
```

can I create a mongo export to a command?

Comment: This is not a duplication, the link refers to bash, I would like to know if spring/mongoTamplate can run an export commend line and how.

Comment: yes the first dupe was for bash script, sorry. this is a dupe of running a command line command from java. just put the string in like you're running it from the console, and voila!

Comment: the problem with using executecommand is that it's used to do things like find and update, things that mongo.exe can do. exporting is a whole separate application, so you just need to invoke that application separately (see the linked question).

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but it might help some

Here is the command to take whole dump of db and it worked for me

```
String command = "mongodump --host " + host + " --port " + port
            + " -d " + dbname + " -o \"" + mongoDbExportFolder + "\"";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```